# Is there good documentation/explanation of what actually tensorflow input_fn and serving_input_receiver_fn does?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there good documentation/explanation of what actually tensorflow input_fn and serving_input_receiver_fn does?

What is the internal concept behind these functions?

Comment: Did you find any examples or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#prepare_serving_inputs):

> During training, an `input_fn()` ingests data and prepares it for use by the model. At serving time, similarly, a `serving_input_receiver_fn()` accepts inference requests and prepares them for the model.